# after upgrade to outlook 2013 Contacts have the default picture in reading pane

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013

I'm using Windows 8 on a domain (using a domain account not a Microsoft account) connecting to Exchange, all my Contacts were outlook contacts with pictures and other data, I could see the picture of the contact in the reading pane and people pane while using Outlook 2010.

After the upgrade to Outlook 2013 I can see my outlook contacts but it appears that they are unavailable in the reading pane because all i can see is the default picture (the default picture picture is also visible in the notifications).

If I put the mouse over the name of the people while in the reading pane all I can see is the  card with the default info (the only data is that the contact is available in the next 8 hours), if i compose a new message and hover the name of the contact i can see the card with all the data (picture, company, etc.).

Is this the default behavior in Outlook 2013 if you are in a domain and not connected to any service or there is a way to show the picture of my contacts in every part of outlook?

Comment: I have the exact same problem, hopefully someone here comes up with an answer. The funny thing is, the rest of the Office 2013 apps now use the picture just fine in the upper right corner, unlike the 2010 apps.