# OutLook 2013 reading Pane (pain) ... screen realestate issue , SEE EDITs

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

Is outlook 2013 restricted to showing an AVATAR or Picture placeholder and font size 57 for the sender address?    I see some info about the embedded and redundant quick butons reply and forward.   But this MEGA who its from concept when there is no picture is annoying.

**Please let there be a solution to screen real-estate extravaganza**

Can I show a simple line with sender and date and size ?   Or something a few million pxs smaller?

I dont like to whinge to much.  I generally like the new tools and you get used to the look. but extreme wastage is a shame.

Looks like similar posts.  But I dont see an answer anywhere
[Reduce visual redundancies in Outlook 2013?](https://superuser.com/questions/518077/reduce-visual-redundancies-in-outlook-2013)
[after upgrade to outlook 2013 Contacts have the default picture in reading pane](https://superuser.com/questions/497181/after-upgrade-to-outlook-2013-contacts-have-the-default-picture-in-reading-pane)

[image: sample issue]

[image: I tried this setting with no effect]

And since the solution seemed it might lie with the "people" settings
I tried this, which removed the picture but did little to fix the real-estate problem

[image: People Settings]

Which now looks like this 
[image: No Pic view]

**EDIT: (after using for 4 months, and connecting to FB and LinkedIn, the benefits outway the negatives).  And i now regularly, Always look at the people Pane.**

Comment: If you supply your LinkedIn and Facebook details to Outlook, you'd get a lot of people's avatars.  It can be quite odd getting a professional business email from someone and seeing their Facebook avatar on it.  You can set Outlook to prioritise LinkedIn or Facebook avatars when both are available.  I think Microsoft account and SharePoint (and possibly federated Active Directory) avatars take priority whatever the case.

Comment: seeing im stuck with the feature i may as well try an put something of value in it . Thanks for this relevant tip :-) +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the most recent MS Office update (version 15.0.4551.1011) adds an option that allows for the message header in the reading pane to be collapsed. It re-sizes the header from this:
[image]

To this:
[image]

Once toggled, it should remain collapsed while switching among messages. Go to the File tab -> Office Account to check your version and update.

[image]

Comment: an improvement indeed.  Still the avatar or Pic if connected to social media.

Answer (score 3):

I too found this huge personal image extremely annoying.  I was able to solve the problem by changing the following setting:

File > Options > People > Show user photographs when available (requires restarting Outlook)

Once I unchecked that box and restarted, the personal image disappeared.

TH